# Using FolderBrowserDialog on a Removable Device / Removable storage

Tags: c#, .net, path, folderbrowserdialog

I'm working on a simple copy tool to copy files off digital cameras. I've written the file copy code, I've got everything hooked up nicely.

The issue I have seems to be with the FolderBrowserDialog. In Vista (I haven't checked XP yet), I can browse to the directories on the camera. However the FolderBrowserDialog will not let me select a directory on the camera. The OK button is greyed out.

Looking at the path for the files on the camera it looks like this:

```
Computer\[Camera Name]\Removable storage\AnotherDirectory\
```

As this is not a valid path (intead of C:\whatever), I'm guessing the FolderBrowserDialog doesn't like this.

It works fine from a valid path name, but not off the camera...

Does anyone have any suggestions to get around this?

**Update**

To confirm oefe's question the path is actually displayed as:

```
Computer\[Camera Name]\Removable storage\AnotherDirectory\
```

ChulioMartinez's suggestion of using SHBrowseForFolder does work, and I will mark as the correct answer. Thanks for your help Chulio.

Comment: How do you get the actual path ? SHBrowseForFolder returns me a valid PIDL but SHGetPathFromIDList fails to return me the path. It works with non-MTP paths but not with MTP paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the location doesn't have a file system representation (path) such as
c:...\my camera.

You should be able to get the PIDL of the folder, (it should be one the the flags for the function), and implement the copy using the COM shell interfaces.

[SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Using PIDL to enumerate a folder](http://www.gtro.com/delphi/shell_e.php)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to map the camera path to a drive letter? (I'm thinking something like "subst" or "net use" from a command prompt.)  Maybe that would fool the FolderBrowserDialog into behaving as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the path from? From the address bar in Explorer? This doesn't display the file system path, but a "user friendly" representation of it.

To get the path, right-click the address bar, and choose "Copy Address as Text" or "Edit Address".